# Copying 4 bytes directly into a DWORD (MSB becomes LSB)

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, endianness

So I was looking at the assembly instructions for `memcpy` and I was wondering if an assembly instruction embedded within the code was responsible for the (Most Significant Byte being altered into the Least Significant Byte) after the `memcpy` being executed.

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/osfmk/x86_64/bcopy.s

```
ENTRY(memcpy)
    movq    %rdx,%rcx
    shrq    $3,%rcx             /* copy by 64-bit words */
    cld // is this instruction responsible for the MSB being switched to LSB
    rep
    movsq
    movq    %rdx,%rcx
    andq    $7,%rcx             /* any bytes left? */
    rep
    movsb
    ret
```

I want `memcpy` to copy `Octet[0]` into the the `DWORD` variable while preserving it as the Most Significant Byte. (31-23)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

unsigned char Octet[4];

Octet[0] = 'A';
Octet[1] = 'B';
Octet[2] = 'C';
Octet[3] = 'D';

unsigned int Dword;

memcpy( &Dword, Octet, 4);

cout << hex << Dword << endl;
```

So after calling memcpy the values are stored into the `DWORD` in the following order.

```
44434241
```

If I created a custom memcpy function while removing the `CLD` instruction would preserve the byte order or replacing it with `SLD` would be a viable solution to get the desired result.

```
41424344
```

Comment: Memcpy() never alters byte-order.  Hacking CLD merely crashes your code.  You went wrong with initializing your Octet[].

Comment: Intel processors are little-endian, so you're getting exactly what's expected (i.e., in a multi-byte number, the first byte will be the least significant). If you want to convert the number from big-endian to whatever the current host uses, consider using something like `ntohl`.

Comment: An array of char does not have an endianness, so it doesn't even make sense to talk about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a quick hack, however I was wondering if other platforms support a similar instruction that is similar to `BSWAP`.

```
    asm volatile ("movl %1,%%eax;\n"
                  "bswapl %%eax;\n"
                  "movl %%eax, %0;\n"
             : "=r" (Dword)
             : "r" (Dword)
             : "%eax"
             );
```

Comment: Couldn't you accomplish this with a single asm instruction: `asm ("bswapl %0" : "+r" (Dword) );`?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the actual assembly code, but on any little endian computer you will get the result you have mentioned. The hex output is always going to print from MSB to LSB and on a little endian computer the MSB will be the last byte.

What it sounds like you want would be best accomplished by:

```
Dword = Octet[0] << 24 | Octet[1] << 16 | Octet[2] << 8 | Octet[3];
```

That's the only standard way I am aware of to put Octet[0] in the MSB down to Octet[3] in the LSB.

Comment: I understand that, but I thought if the Direction flag was altered. I would get the desired result.

Comment: Well, your question is confusing because you are suggesting that the MSB/LSB is getting changed/swapped, when in fact there is no MSB/LSB when it is in byte form.

Comment: I know of the shift method, but I was looking for something more on the fly. That wouldn't do multiple copy/shift operations. Well I'm sorry for having altered your perception, but it always gets this painful in low-level.

Comment: It's not a matter of perception. Character arrays (which is what memcpy works on) do not have MSBs or LSBs. Therefore to say that memcpy is transforming the MSB into the LSB is incorrect.